# How do I add a label, or other element dynamically to a windows form panel?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

So this is probably a pretty basic question, but I am working with dragging and dropping ListBox Items onto a panel which will create components depending on the value.

As an easy example, I need it to be able to create a new Label on the panel when an item from the ListBox is dropped onto the panel.

I have the following code, but am not sure how to dynamically add the Label to the panel once it is dropped.

Here is my sample code...

```
namespace TestApp
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("First Name");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Last Name");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Phone");
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox box = (ListBox)sender;
        String selectedValue = box.Text;
        DoDragDrop(selectedValue.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
    }

    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Label newLabel = new Label();
        newLabel.Name = "testLabel";
        newLabel.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();

        //Do I need to call either of the following code to make it do this?
        newLabel.Visible = true;
        newLabel.Show();

        panel1.Container.Add(newLabel);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
    //Do I need to call either of the following code to make it do this?
    newLabel.Visible = true;
    newLabel.Show();
```

is unnecessary.

---

```
newLabel.AutoSize = true;
```

is, most probably, necessary to give it a size.

---

```
    panel1.Container.Add(newLabel);
```

must be replaced by

```
    newLabel.Parent = panel1;
```

### But, your method should work, unless the drag doesn't work.

---

Found the bug. It must be `panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);` or `newLabel.Parent = panel1;` instead of `panel1.Container.Add(newLabel);`. `Container` is something else.

Answer (score 4):

replace

```
panel1.Container.Add(newLabel);
```

by

```
panel1.Controls.Add(newLabel);
```

i think it will add newLabel object to the panel

Answer (score 0):

I think Visible is set to True by default, but it's very possible you need to refresh the panel after adding the label in order to see the label.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you'll still need to add the label to the form's `ControlCollection` for it to render. So add something like the following to the end of the `DragDrop` method:

```
this.Controls.Add(newLabel);
```

Comment: This will add the label to the form as well. If not just blow up from trying to add one control to two parent controls.